# Why do I get an error message about the tr element in HTML5?

Tags: razor

I changed to HTML 5 and suddenly I get an error where I didn’t before. The error message is:

> Validation (HTML5): Text is not allowed between the opening and
>   closing tags for element tr’.

I don't see any plain text and when I try to change @: to @ or delete it I get a message that says 'end tag without a beginning tag'.  I don't see where I've entered any text here.  Please help.

```
<tr id="listTableRow">          
@{
    int cnt = 0;
    List<SchoolIn.ViewModels.EnrolledCourseData> courses = ViewBag.Courses;         
    List<String> dayofclass = ViewBag.classDay;
    List<String> theListOfTeachers = ViewBag.teacherList;
    List<String> teacher = ViewBag.instructors;
    List<SchoolIn.Models.Enrollment> LoDays = ViewBag.lDays;
    List<String> listofinstructors = ViewBag.listOfInstructors;
    List<int> coursesIds = new List<int>();
    foreach (var course in courses.Select((x, i) => new { Data = x, Index = i }))
    {
        int currentIndex = course.Index;
        String selectedday = "";
        String selectedteacher = "";

        if (cnt++ % 4 == 0)
        {
            @:  </tr> <tr>
        }
```

Hi CoderOll, thanks for helping me out.  Your suggestion was the solution for the first  tag but the second one that I pasted below still seems to think that there is text between  even though I have as you can see below.  I research the Razor explicit code nuggets and found information about wrapping ambiguous code statements like…

```
  @foreach(var item in order.Items){
Var itemName-(GetOrderItemName<string>(item)):
 <li>@itemName</li>…
```

But I couldn’t find any code that Razor may mistake for markup between  and .  I even tried replacing < and > with < and > but that won’t work.  Do you have any ideas which part of the code may be interperted as text?

Thanks for all your help.

```
 <tr>

    }

      @: <td id="days" >  

      <input type="checkbox"  id="checkbox" name="selectedCourses" value="@course.Data.CourseID"  @(Html.Raw(course.Data.Assigned ? "checked=\"checked\"" : ""))/> 

               @course.Data.Title  @: <br />

    if (dayofclass != null && course.Index < dayofclass.Count())
    {


        String sellectedDay = dayofclass.ElementAt(course.Index);                                           
        selectedday = sellectedDay;



        if (theListOfTeachers != null && course.Index < theListOfTeachers.Count())
        {


            String selectedTeacher = theListOfTeachers.ElementAt(course.Index);

            selectedteacher = selectedTeacher;
        }


    }
    if (selectedday == "")
    { 

         @Html.DropDownList("searchString", Model.WeekDays.Select(s => new SelectListItem {      Text = s.ToString(), Value = s.ToString(), Selected = s.ToString().Equals("Day") }), new { @class = "daylists" }) 
           @Html.DropDownList("instructorString", listofinstructors.Select(tch => new  SelectListItem { Text = tch.ToString(), Value = tch.ToString(), Selected = tch.ToString().Equals("Pick One") }), new { @class = "teacherlists" })


    }


    else


        if (Model.Enrollments != null)
        {




                 @Html.DropDownList("searchString", Model.Enrollments.FirstOrDefault().WeekDays.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s.ToString(), Value = s.ToString(), Selected = s.ToString().Equals(selectedday) }), new { @class = "daylists" }) 


                                @Html.DropDownList("instructorString", listofinstructors.Select(tch => new SelectListItem { Text = tch.ToString(), Value = tch.ToString(), Selected = tch.ToString().Equals(selectedteacher) }), new { @class = "teacherlists" })


        }





                                 @:</td> 


}





                                @:</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have a guess (sorry i have not used razor but i have some html experience).

```
 if (cnt++ % 4 == 0)
    {
        @:  </tr> <tr>  <<-- maybe this should be <tr> </tr> 
    }
```

have you tried changing or removing this line?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The message

> Validation (HTML5): Text is not allowed between the opening and
>   closing tags for element tr’.

Simply means that you're missing the `TD` or `TH` elements. since `TR` means a 'Table Row', and a Row only wraps a set of columns, you need a `TD` or a `TH` element to wrap your text.

You don't show the rest of your code, but you probably have something like this:

```
@foreach (var course in courses)
{
    if (cnt++ % 4 == 0)
    {
        @:  </tr> <tr>
    }

    @course.Data <-- Outputting text after 'TR' without enclosing it in a TD/TH
}
```

Try something like:

```
<td>
    @course.Data
</td>
```